# Can't assign variable value like this: a = 3.2, b = 5, c = 'hello' in Python

Tags: python, syntax

Why I can't assign variable value like this:

```
a = 3.2, b = 5, c = 'hello'
```

then:

```
print(a)
print(b)
print(c)
```

in Python.

Comment: Why do you want to?  Even in C, which supports the comma operator, it is frowned upon except in a narrow use (`for` loop).

Answer (score 4):

Because those are **separate statements**. In Python statements are **separated** by either a **new line**, or a **semicolon** (`;`).

So the following works:

```
a = 3.2; b = 5; c = 'hello'
```

or:

```
a = 3.2
b = 5
c = 'hello'
```

Or you can use **tuple assignment**:

```
a, b, c = 3.2, 5, 'hello'
```

Usually a comma is used to separate two identifiers (e.g. parameters in a function) or expressions (for tuple, list,... construction).

Answer (score 2):

You have to do them as seperate statements, like:

```
a = 3.2
b = 5
c = 'hello'
```

---

But if you did want them on one line, seperate with a semi-colon (`;`):

```
a = 3.2; b = 5; c = 'hello'
```

But this is frowned upon.

---

You can also construct a temporary tuple and do assignment by expanding it:

```
a, b, c = 3.2, 5, 'hello'
```

Note that this is the same as:

```
temp = (3.2, 5, 'hello')
a, b, c = temp
```

So it creates a temporary object.

---

The other way you can assign to multiple variables is to just the same object:

```
a = b = c = 3.2  # They all equal 3.2.
```

Answer (score 1):

You should separate them with semicolons ";" :

```
a = 3.2; b = 5; c = 'Hello'
```

Or declare them in different lines :

```
a = 3.2
b = 5
c = 'Hello'
```